# count couplets from a list with \r\n line breaks

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get a count of couplets from a set of lyrics. Let's say the lyrics are:

```
I saw a little hermit crab
His coloring was oh so drab

It’s hard to see the butterfly
Because he flies across the sky
```

etc etc...

```
Once upon a time
She made a little rhyme
Of course, of course

Before we say again
The pain the pain
A horse, a horse

Lightening, thunder, all around
Soon the rain falls on the ground

I tire of writing poems and rhyme
```

They're stored in the db as a string, separated by `u'\r\n'` and via string.splitlines(Tree), the object has them stored like this:

```
>>> lyrics[6].track_lyrics['lyrics']
[u'I saw a little hermit crab\r\n', u'His coloring was oh so drab\r\n', u'\r\n', u'It\u2019s hard to see the butterfly\r\n', u'Because he flies across the sky\r\n', u'\r\n',  u'\r\n', u'Before we say again\r\n', u'The pain the pain\r\n', u'A horse, a horse\r\n', u'\r\n', u'Lightening, thunder, all around\r\n', u'Soon the rain falls on the ground\r\n', u'\r\n', u'I tire of writing poems and rhyme\r\n']
```

I can get close with this:

```
len([i for i in lyrics if i != "\r\n"]) / 2
```

But it also counts sets of one, three or more lines as couplets.

I'm kind of getting there with this, which basically says if there's a `"\r\n"` one line previous and two lines later, we're a couplet:

```
>>> for k,v in enumerate(lyric_list):
...     if lyric_list[k+2] == "\r\n" and lyric_list[k-1] == "\r\n":
...             print(v)
... 
It’s hard to see the butterfly

Hear the honking of the goose


Lightening, thunder, all around
```

But, of course:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I could use `try` and `except IndexError:` with something like this:

```
>>> if len(lyric_string) > 1:
...     for k, v in enumerate(lyric_string):
...             if k == 0 and lyric_string[k+2] == "\r\n":
...                     print(v)
...             elif lyric_string[k-1] == "\r\n" and lyric_string[k+2] == "\r\n":
...                     print(v)
... 
I saw a little hermit crab

It’s hard to see the butterfly

Hear the honking of the goose

His red sports car is just a dream

The children like the ocean shore

I made the cookies one by one

My cat, she likes to chase a mouse,

Lightening, thunder, all around

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And I considered doing something like this which is even uglier and doesn't work! (only gets the first and last lines):

```
>>> if len(lyric_string) > 1:
...     for k, v in enumerate(lyric_string):
...             if k == 0 and lyric_string[k+2] == "\r\n":
...                     print(v)
...             elif lyric_string[k-1] == "\r\n" and (k+2 > len(lyric_string) \
...                                                     or lyric_string[k+2] == "\r\b"):
...                     print(v)
```

But I bet there's a much more eloquent and even pythonic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the assumption that a couplet is a set of lines containing 2 lines.

You can achieve this by splitting into blocks, then counting the amount of lines in each block. In this example I count the number of newlines in a block (should be 1 in a couplet).

```
>>> text = """I saw a little hermit crab
... His coloring was oh so drab
... 
... It’s hard to see the butterfly
... Because he flies across the sky
... 
... etc etc...
... 
... Once upon a time
... She made a little rhyme
... Of course, of course
... 
... Before we say again
... The pain the pain
... A horse, a horse
... 
... Lightening, thunder, all around
... Soon the rain falls on the ground
... 
... I tire of writing poems and rhyme
... """.replace('\n', '\r\n')
>>> len([block for block in text.split('\r\n\r\n') if block.count('\r\n') == 1])
3
```

This is also assuming that there are exactly two newlines between each block. To handle 2+ newlines, you could use:

```
import re
...
.. block for block in re.split(r'(?:\r\n){2,}', text) ..
```

Comment: updated the regex to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928630/find-2-or-more-newlines/27928748#27928748`, based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928630/find-2-or-more-newlines/27928748#27928748

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler approach: Join the entire array with "" and count the occurrences of newlines.

```
>>> s = """Once upon a time
... She made a little rhyme
... Of course, of course
...
... Before we say again
... The pain the pain
... A horse, a horse
...
... Lightening, thunder, all around
... Soon the rain falls on the ground
...
... I tire of writing poems and rhyme"""
```

and then just do:

```
>>> s.strip().count("\n\n") + 1
4
```

To get `s` in the above code, you will need to do an additional join. An example

```
s = "".join(lyrics[6].track_lyrics['lyrics'])
```

I use `\n` on my system, you might have to use `\r\n` on yours.

Comment: thanks for `s = "".join(a_list)`, however I don't think `s.strip().count("\n\n") + 1` works, because a couplet is when exactly two lines are together - which I will edit the question to specify - so the couplet_count in `s` is actually 1.