# Find 2 or more Newlines

Tags: regex, python-2.7

My string looks like:

```
'I saw a little hermit crab\r\nHis coloring was oh so drab\r\n\r\nIt\u2019s hard to see the butterfly\r\nBecause he flies across the sky\r\n\r\nHear the honking of the goose\r\nI think he\u2019s angry at the moose\r\n\r\'
```

And I need to split it wherever there are two or more `newlines`.

Am using the `re` module, of course.

On this particular string `re.split(r'\r\n\r\n+', text)` works, but it wouldn't catch `\r\n\r\n\r\n`, right?

I have tried `re.split(r'(\r\n){2,}', text)`, which splits at *every* line and `re.split(r'\r\n{2,}', text)`, which creates a list of `len()` 1.

Shouldn't `re.split(r'(\r\n){2,}', text) == re.split(r'\r\n\r\n', text)` be `True` for a string in which there are no consecutive occurrences of more than 2 `\r\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.split(r'(\r\n){2,}', text)` doesn't split at every line. It does exactly what you want, *except* it preserves one occurence of `\r\n` because you've enclosed it in a capturing group. Use a non-capturing group instead:

```
(?:\r\n){2,}
```

Here you can see what the difference is:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?:\r\n){2,}', 'foo\r\n\r\nbar')
['foo', 'bar']
>>> re.split(r'(\r\n){2,}', 'foo\r\n\r\nbar')
['foo', '\r\n', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [Non-capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) group instead of a capturing group when you execute the call to `re.split()`. In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split), it is clearly stated that using a capturing group retains the separator pattern:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

```
re.split(r'(?:\r\n){2,}', text)
```